# Adding bbox of my map with Expression Builder into text field

Tags: qgis, print-composer, extents

I was commissioned to create a simple print layout. The basic-layout is very simple, it just contains one map with OopenStreetMap-layer.

I want to add the Xmin, Xmax, Ymin and Ymax of this map (like all the values in the extention-tab) as text field. The text field should then display the coordinates of the map's corners, and should automatically adjust when I zoom in or out, so copy&paste is not an option.

Comment: I think what you want is to add a coordinate grid to the map. You can check this part of the documentation for more info: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#grids

Answer (score 3):

To get the coordinates of the upper right corner of your map, use the following expression:

```
round(x_max(map_get(item_variables('Karte'),'map_extent')))||', '||round(y_max(map_get(item_variables('Karte'),'map_extent')))
```

`item_variables('Karte')` points at the item you want to work with. You need to replace `Karte` with the name you gave your map item.

`map_get([...],'map_extent')` grabs the extent of the item you're pointing at. In this case you're returned a geometry.

Once you get the geometry, the rest is rather easy:

Use `y_min`, `y_max`, `x_min` and `x_max` followed by the geometry you need the coordinates of to grab said coordinates. Combine min/max and x/y in order to create the fitting coordinate pairs. `||', '||` concatenates these coordinates.

I added the `round` function since I tried this using a UTM-zone and didn't want unnecessarily long numbers. If you're working with DMS-coordinates, please remove `round` since it'd probably break the expression.