# Map orientation along parallels

Tags: qgis, print-composer, utm, mapping

I'm trying to make a precision topology map in QGIS 3.14 where my map's corners are defined by geographic coords: this means it should have the same range of degrees on top as on the bottom, and same on left as on the right side of map. For example:

[image]

I use the UTM coordinate system, U34 zone, EPSG: 32634.

Coords of my corners:
Top-left: '549108, 5506822'
Top-right: '553523, 5506822'
Bottom-left: '549108, 5502204'
Bottom-right: '553523, 5502204'

Actually I feel like my map in the print-composer is oriented in this way (red square is my map range):

[image]

And my desired output should look like this (along the parallels):
[image]

Comment: Are you aware that the spatial extent of geographical degree in km varies with the latitude? Is there a reason you mix degree and an UTM-zone in your map?

Comment: @Erik should i care about km? if the U34 zone is from 21ºE to 27ºE there is always 6º of range. if my map got (i.g. 3º of length) there would be always 2 sheets per zone. Am i wrong?

I use UTM to visualize some values on out-of-bounds description, like kilometers net etc. maybe i should use different coord system to visualize my map properly?

Comment: Okay, since you only "have a feeling", I suggest your actually have a look at the coordinates of your corners. Use [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371840/adding-bbox-of-my-map-with-expression-builder-into-text-field/371848#371848) as a guide, and add the actual coordinates to your question.

Comment: okay, i just updated coords. but how does it help me?

Comment: This shows that a) your feeling is wrong, the map is perfectly aligned with the borders of the UTM zone/aligned north, b) your map extent is definitely not 2.3° wide both at top and bottom and c) you can't confirm that your corner coordinates are as you intend them to be.

Comment: b) it was just example, but... what should i do to have a map with 2'30" width and 3'45" length and scale 1:10000? and also i need to display coords of corners in DMS. it should look like: Top-left: '50°02' 30"N, 21°00' 00" E' Top-right: '50°02' 30"N, 21°03' 45" E' Bottom-left: '50°00' 00"N, 21°00' 00" E ' Bottom-right: '50°00' 00"N, 21°03' 45" E'

Comment: If you want to align the map with EPSG4326, you need to set its CRS accordingly (properties of your map element in the composer) - but this will lead to distortion. In the same dialogue you may set the extent and scale of your map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112547/discussion-between-daniel-sobolewski-and-erik).